# How to migrate from Artifactory to Nexus 2.8.0-05

Tags: maven, nexus

I installed nexus-2.8.0-05-bundle.tar.gz and now I am trying to migrate old (single) repo from Artifactory.

How can I achieve this (Debian7)?

I read about migration plugin but I cannot seem to find the right one... I unzipped nexus-migration-plugin-packaging-1.5-webapp.zip into the nexus installation folder but it doesn't seem to work..or at least I cannot find any related actions from the web admin console localhost:8081/nexus.

Cheers,
newbie

Comment: I don't know if this is the 'proper' way to do it, but you can just copy the repo's root directories (org, com, etc) into the required nexus repo directory, and tell nexus to rebuild its indexes.

Comment: I am with JFrog and wondering why would you switch? We usually see opposite direction traffic (Oracle, CA, EMC, VMWare, Nokia, and who's not). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate to Nexus you would use the export tool of Artifactory to get the repositories as plain files and folders structure.

Then you create a repo in Nexus and simply copy that storage into place.

Further details are available in the Nexus book [migration chapter.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/migrating.html)

You can also ping us via a [support ticket](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/migrating.html) or via the [mailings lists or hipchat channel.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/participate)

PS: The migration plugin is deprecated and should not be used.